# NgRx how to extend EntityState and EntityAdapter

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I want to extend EntityState interface to also contain a `cache` prop and methods of EntityAdapter to manipulate this cache.
I faced the problem that I can't easily 'patch' methods of EntityAdapter.
Ideally I want to call method `createCachedEntityAdapter` and it should return a type whos methods like `setAll` expecnt and return my updated 'cached' interface. What I have so far:

```
// Interface for cached entity
export interface CachedEntityState<T> extends EntityState<T> {
    cache: Dictionary<T>;
}

//Root method to call to create patched entity adapter
export const createCachedEntityAdapter = <T>(options?: {
    selectId?: IdSelector<T>;
    sortComparer?: false | Comparer<T>;
}) => {

    //create a base one
    const cacheAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
        selectId: options.selectId,
        sortComparer: options.sortComparer
    })

    //extend it
    const patched = patchMethods(cacheAdapter);
}

// This method patches each needed method
const patchMethods = <T>(adapter: EntityAdapter<T>) => {
    const newSetAll = patchArrayMethod(adapter.setAll, adapter)

    return {
        ...adapter,
        setAll: newSetAll,
    }
}

// methods like setAll has different semantic rather than methods like addOne, so to patch it need to use a little bit different logic
const patchArrayMethod = <T, S extends CachedEntityState<T>>(method: (entities: T[], state: S) => S, adapter: EntityAdapter<T>): (entities: T[], state: S) => S => {
    return (entities: T[], state: S) => {
        return method(entities, {
            ...state,
            cache: saveCache(entities, state, adapter.selectId)
        })
    }
}

//Just gets new entities and saves it to the cache prop
const saveCache = <T, S extends CachedEntityState<T>>(entities: T[], state: S, selectId: IdSelector<T>): Dictionary<T> => {
    const newCache = entities.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const id = selectId(curr);

        return {
            ...acc,
            [id]: curr
        }
    }, {} as Dictionary<T>);

    return {
        ...state.cache,
        ...newCache
    }
}
```

This code compiles fine but because I didn't add any return type for `patchMethods` function. And it literally returns completely new time which almost doesn't have anything in common with `EntityAdapter` because methods I patched.

Is it possible to extend it without introducing completely separate type from  EntityAdapter?